# Checkbox group, submit button only if at least one checkbox is checked Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox, angular-validation

I have a checkbox group with 3 items. I created it with Angular 5.0.5 and Clarity vm. I want my function to check if at least one of the checkboxes is checked and THEN go at the next page, which is a wizard. Until now the wizard opens without checking if at least one checkbox is selected.

My html looks like this:

```
<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
<td>
<input  type="checkbox" name="allowNext" [(ngModel)]="item.chosen">
</td>
<td>
{{item.name}}
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
</form>
<button [disabled] class="btn btn-primary" (click)="go()"> Next </button>
```

my Typescript for it looks like this:

```
items= [
    {name: 'checkbox1', chosen: false},
    {name: 'checkbox2', chosen: false},
    {name: 'checkbox3', chosen: false}
  ];
 go() {
 if(this.items.chosen === true) {
 this.wizard.open();
 ngOnInit () {}
 constructor( public router: Router) {}
```

could you guys please help me define the function correclty?

Comment: you have to check if every select is checked. You can use a loop or map and reduce from Arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.items.some(i => i.chosen)
```

will check if at least one item is chosen

Answer (score -1):

With JQuery you can simple do this :

```
if ($('#frmTest input:checked').length > 0 ) {

  //your code

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need it to work with Typescript/ Angular . I tried if 
    ((this.checked).length > 0 ) {  this.wizard.open(); } but it didnt work